# How can I convert a date format from my plugin so it saves correctly?

Tags: plugin-development, datetime

I have a plugin that includes a [datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I initialize the datepicker like this

**javascript**

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    'format': 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    'todayHighlight': true
});
```

I am saving the date from my plugin like this:

```
$myDate = craft()->request->getPost('myDate');
if ($myDate) {
    DateTime::createFromString($myDate, craft()->timezone);
}

$fieldsLocation = craft()->request->getParam('fieldsLocation', 'fields');
$entry->setContentFromPost($fieldsLocation);
```

Because I have designated this field to be required, I get an error back saying that the field cannot be blank. Even though I have chosen a date.

If I change my datepicker to use *this* format:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    'format': 'yyyy/mm/dd',
    'todayHighlight': true
});
```

Everything works.
I like how "human/U.S" friendly the top example is vs. `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Since I am populating the entry with this:

```
$entry->setContentFromPost($fieldsLocation);
```

Is there a way to convert what is passed in to the correct format Craft is looking for?

I've tried something like:

```
$date = date(str_replace('/', '-', craft()->request->getPost('myDate')));

$myDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

But that is getting overwritten by this guy still:

```
entry->setContentFromPost($fieldsLocation);
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `$entry->setContentFromPost($fieldsLocation);` you should be able to add another line to explicitly set your calculated date.

```
$entry->setContent(array('fieldName' => $myDate));
```

Then just proceed with saving the entry as normal.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I could call `setContent` back to back like that.